# show the LSTM memory cell's state value and forget gate value

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm using tf.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell, I want to show the forget gate value while training. I use tf.get_variable(), but there is something wrong. How can I make it?

```
with tf.variable_scope("new_c", reuse=True):
      v1 = tf.get_variable("new_c")  # The same as v above.
```

The  error:

> Variable new_c/new_c does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?